# NoSuchMethodError using JSONArray in org.json

Tags: java, json

## Error Message

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.isEmpty()Z

## My Scenario

I tried using the `isEmpty()` method of `JSONArray`from the `org.json` JAR.

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE. I'm not using anything close to reflection in my code. I declare a `JSONArray`, and after some lines trying to check if it is empty or not, however I get this Error when trying to use `isEmpty()`.

I did work around the issue simply by using `jsonArray.length() > 0`, but the error message is what fascinates me. I looked into the de-compiled **.class** file of JSONArray, and the method `isEmpty()` **exists**, and has a **public access modifier**. Futhermore, InteliiJ is suggesting me I can use `isEmpty()` when typing the code. So what could be causing this error to occur?

## Code Example

```
JSONArray filesJsonArray = new JSONArray();

JSONObject fileObject = new JSONObject();
fileObject.put("fileId",fileId);
fileObject.put("fileName",fileName);
fileObject.put("mimeType",mimeType);

filesJsonArray.put(fileObject);

if (!filesJsonArray.isEmpty()){ //the condition check here throws the error.
}
```

(Catch blocks were dismissed for brevity)

## My Imports

In the class I'm using this code, this is all my imports

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Base64;
```

Comment: Which package are you using? `org.json.simple.JSONArray` this has `isEmpty()` method. `org.json.JSONArray` this one does not have the method.

Comment: According to the documentation there is no `isEmpty()` method. Maybe you have an issue with IntelliJ, have you tried compiling from the command line? Maybe check File->Project structure to see that IntelliJ uses the right library

Comment: @PrashantZombade using `org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: @DanielB., check with `org.json.simple.JSONArray` . You will have to handle `JSONException` while putting the objects.

Comment: @PrashantZombade There is a catch block for JSONException in my code. I'm not using org.json.simple.JSONArray, Im not familiar with this pacakge.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In my project structure I have one JAR file that is relevant to JSON and it is named `json-20180813.jar`, which was downloaded from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813, which belongs to `org.json`

Comment: Well did you try to build your project from outside of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 9):

If you are using spring boot, then you can try this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

It worked for me..

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking at this, the main problem is with JSONAssert.

To confirm, use whatever dependency graph tool you have to verify that JSONAssert is adding "android-json".

Example for maven:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

android-json provides its own implementations of org.json.* objects that aren't up to date.  So exclude them as JSONAssert dependencies.

Example for maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
           <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

That should save you from this problem while letting you use the great output of JSONAssert!

Answer (score 2):

You need to clean the package of *org.json* dependency from *spring-boot-starter-test artifactId*, here is how to clean any depency (considering I was using *spring-boot-starter-parent* 2.4.4)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: And how to find these dependecies conflicts ? Type mvn dependency:tree into your root folder from a command line tool, it will give you the list of dependencies used, it can looks tedious, but this is the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I believe you added to your project

```
compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
```

Cause it seems like you've confused 2 classes: `org.json.JSONArray` with `org.json.simple.JSONArray`.
First one doesn't have that method and the second one does.
Here are code examples for both classes:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.json.JSONArray

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.json.simple.JSONArray

So as a solution i’d recommend clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: This is not the case. I'm not using `org.json.simple.JSONArray` anywhere in my code. Just `org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: @DanielB. SO you say that cleaning and rebuilding the project doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error after i added to my project:

```
<dependency>    
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

After that I **cleaned and updated dependencies**,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but posting this in case this might be useful to someone.

Here is what my updated dependency

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In my case, the `JSONArray` from `com.vaadin.external.google` from `android-json` was being used, instead of `org.json.JSONArray` which has the `spliterator()` throwing

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.spliterator()Ljava/util/Spliterator;`

here is the code which threw that

```
  JSONArray someJsonArray = getSomeJsonArray();
  if (someJsonArray != null) {
    List<SecretEntry> secretEntries = (List)StreamSupport.stream(someJsonArray.spliterator(), false).map((obj) -> {
      return (JSONObject)obj;
...
```

And, I could not exclude `org.skyscreamer.jsonassert`, since it was being used  by the `assertJSONEqual()` called by `andExpect(content().json(getJsonBody()))`

here is the code

```
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Inject
 private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

 mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
 MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
        get("basePath").header(
            "headerName", "headerValue")).andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().json(getJsonBody())).andReturn();
```

}